# How to use underscore in jade template

Tags: node.js, pug, underscore.js

I want to use underscore function in jade template, like this

```
p= _.keys(user)
```

Not for client javascript, for in redering.

Through I did require 'underscore' in app.js, did not get along well.
Of course it work properly in app.js.

```
ReferenceError: xxxxxxx _ is not defined
```

this is template error message.
any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are using [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/) (presumably you would be since you're using Jade) you can add underscore as a [view helper](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#app.helpers()).

```
app.helpers({
    _: require("underscore")
});
```

**UPDATE** Using Express 3+, the above will no longer work, use [`app.locals`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals) instead:

```
app.locals._ = require("underscore");
```

Comment: super awesome answer. Solved 3 problems for me! thank you

Answer (score 5):

In Express 3.x helpers were removed. Instead use middleware and `res.locals`

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.locals._ = require('underscore');
  next();
});
```